# Running .sh scripts in git bash from Qt App in Windows

Tags: bash, git, qt, sh, qprocess

I have an application in Qt on Windows and I want to run a script .sh when I press a button and save the output on plainTextEdit.

This is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonSTART_clicked()
{
  QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
        ui->plainTextEditResults->setPlainText(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    });
    process->start("git-bash.exe", QStringList{QString("./"),"path/script1.sh"});

    //ui->plainTextEditResults->setPlainText(QString::number(process->exitCode()));
}
```

Script: (I try with #!/bin/bash, same result)

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World!"
```

Problem is my script doesn't run (I try this, no effects:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World!" >> test.json)
```

But exitCode() is 0.
Some help? I would like run the scripts in git-bash or cmd, if is posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it so that the status code is 0 (normal output) and without the window opening and closing very quickly.

The first time I run the cmd, and in cmd I call bash and then in bash my script

```
QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
connect(process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
        ui->plainTextEditResults->appendPlainText(QString("exitStatus:") + QString::number(exitStatus));
        ui->plainTextEditResults->appendPlainText(QString("exitStatus normal:") + QString::number(QProcess::NormalExit));
        ui->plainTextEditResults->appendPlainText(QString("exitStatus crash:") + QString::number(QProcess::CrashExit));
        ui->plainTextEditResults->appendPlainText(QString("exitCode:") +QString::number(exitCode));
    });
processArgs+="/c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i -- \"D:/path/script1.sh\"\"";
    process->setNativeArguments(processArgs);
    process->start("cmd.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `git-bash.exe` on your path?

Otherwise you would have to specify the full path to the executable; `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`.

Comment: it works, but it gives me an errorStatus=1(Crash) and errorCode(-1073741819). And a git-bash window opens and closes quickly.

Comment: `process->start("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe ",QStringList()<<"D:/path/script1.sh");`